# Free stock footage for open-source project

Tags: open-source, video-processing

I'm implementing a video processing framework. Where can I get high quality free stock footage so I could use it to demonstrate functionality? The framework is open source, so I'd like the videos to be as well (I'm not charging for the final product, so I wouldn't want to pay for the videos either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internet archive has a section with [movies in the public domain](http://www.archive.org/details/movies), you could for example use [Night of the Living Dead](http://www.archive.org/details/night_of_the_living_dead). Another option would be creative commons licensed videos, using for example this [Flickr query](http://www.flickr.com/search/?q=&l=commderiv&ss=2&ct=0&mt=videos&w=all&adv=1)